# WARN New offset is higher than latest offset. Why I cannot change offset in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, offset

I use the last version Kafka 1.1.0

Use command:

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9093 --describe --group notifications-service-group
```

[image: result]

Then I try change offset for topic "notification", partition № 4:

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9093 --group notifications-service-group --reset-offsets --topic notification:4 --to-offset 229400
```

and I see error:
**WARN New offset (229400) is higher than latest offset for topic partition notification-4. Value will be set to 0 (kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$)**

I try use any numbers from 1 to 229400 and get same error.

What means that error and how solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your command to update the offset you have the topic set as `notification` but the topic name is `notifications` with an '**s**'. So `notification:4` -> `notifications:4` should work.